# How to Install dnsmasq on Ubuntu?

Tags: dnsmasq

I tried on ubuntu 16.04 and 20.04, however I cannot install `dnsmasq`.

The error I get is:

```
Package dnsmasq is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  dnsmasq-base

E: Package 'dnsmasq' has no installation candidate
```

Is this no longer a package available on ubuntu repos?

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: Yes the package is available in repositories if you look, but you mention an off-topic release & an on-topic one; if you wish to ask about both you should be asking on SE *Unix & Linux* as the 16.04 reference is off-topic here (only releases in *standard* support are on-topic here).  We can't read your `sudo apt update` output to look for issues so I'd provide that when your question is on-topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) See https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=dnsmasq for details.

Comment: Ah, yes enabling that repo would have worked. I was using the live cd versions. I ended up installing `make` and compiling from source downloaded from https://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/

Comment: Worthwhile to spend some time understanding the [ubuntu repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)